# How to make links show up in a random position on each page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project where I want clickable links to appear in a different position each time you visit/refresh the page. So far, I've gotten this:

```
<script>
for (var i=1; i <= 1; i++) {
    var x = Math.max(0, Math.min(70, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)));
    $('<div1>').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '150px',
        height: '50px',
        left: x + '%',
    }).html("<p>CLICK ME<p>").appendTo('body');
}
```

This code does what I want it to do, but I can't figure out how to add a link to this. Adding an `<a>` tag to the .html part of it doesn't work (I've also never really used jQuery before). I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix this.

Comment: `.html("<p><a href='foo.html'>CLICK ME</a><p>")` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need jQuery for this, here is how you can do it:

> jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nt6zodmh/

```
var top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); // number between 1-99
var left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); // number between 1-99
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'https://google.com' // set href
a.innerHTML = 'CLICK ME';
// set style
a.style.position = 'absolute';
a.style.top = top+'%';
a.style.left = left+'%';
// add to body
document.body.appendChild(a)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! This worked and is much easier for me to understand too.

Comment: Technically speaking, you don't *need* jQuery for anything.